# Amp image is not showing on my product page

Tags: html, iis, asp-classic, implementation

How do I implement amp-img tags? When I nest an amp-img tag on an existing img tag, the image is not displayed.

My site is built in classic ASP, running on an IIS server.  Do I need to make changes in IIS?

Comment: You may have incorrect base url or src address. Check the console if there is not found error about source image?

Comment: My existing html for product image

<img alt='D6564 Cream Dahlia Rizwan Ahmed Wedding Dresses Latest Party Dresses Trends Pakistan' 
 src="/images/products/women5/6564-2017.jpg" 
 class="img-rounded" 
 style="max-width:100%;" 
 style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC">

Amp-img nest

<amp-img alt='D6564 Cream Dahlia Rizwan Ahmed Wedding Dresses Latest Party Dresses Trends Pakistan' 
 src="/images/products/women5/6564-2017.jpg" 
 class="img-rounded" 
 style="max-width:100%;" 
 style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC">
</amp-img>

Both image locations are same

Comment: Dont you receive "not found" error in browser console?

Comment: [http://www.bargello.com/Bridal+Wear_107_290_1.htm](http://www.bargello.com/Bridal+Wear_107_290_1.htm) works now